# Why is my webpage printing an extra blank page?

Tags: html, css-print

I can't figure out why my html document is printing an extra blank page.

I tried shrinking the content and increasing the margins of the printed page to no avail.

The document should produce only one printed page but it is producing a second blank page.

Here is the link to the app: https://wesleyhedrick.github.io/DragandDrop/draganddrop.html

Comment: It's because you have margin and padding on your body element along with `100vh` as the height. all those combined make more than 100% of the height which is causing the overflow and printing more than 1 page. if you remove the `100vh` you should only print 1 page. There are also ways around that if you need that `100vh` such as removing the margin and padding from the body and adding it to inner elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the CSS attribute `height: 100vh` from your `body` and you will get just one page